# why cant use subclass of SKShapenode?

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit

I use a sub class here called `Enemy` that inherit from `SKShapeNode`, the issue here is when i check the collision between `bullet` and `enemy` and I grab enemy's `health` it says `found nil while unwrapping`.

here is my code :

```
private func drawEnemy() {
        let (color, edge) = randomColorandEdge()
        let nextEnemyPosition = determineNextEnemyPosition(edge: Int(edge))
        let enemyPosition = spawnAtRandomPosition(edge: nextEnemyPosition)
        let enemyCircle = Enemy(scene: self, color: color, radius: globalRadius, position: enemyPosition)
        let enemy = enemyCircle.drawEnemy()
        world.addChild(enemy)
        numberOfEnemies += 1
        enemy.name = String(numberOfEnemies)
        runToCenter(enemy: enemy)
    }

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bodyType.bullet.rawValue) && (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bodyType.enemy.rawValue) {
            let hitter = contact.bodyB.node as? SKShapeNode
            let enemy = contact.bodyA.node as? Enemy
            hitter?.removeFromParent()
            let health = enemy?.getHealth()
            if health! > 0 {
                enemy?.setHealth(amount: health! - 1)
            }else {
                enemy?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my `Enemy` class :

```
class Enemy: SKShapeNode {

    private var health: Int = 5
    private var color: SKColor!
    private var radius: CGFloat!
    private var s: SKScene!
    private var pos: CGPoint!
    private var enemy: SKShapeNode!

    init(scene: SKScene, color: SKColor, radius: CGFloat, position: CGPoint) {
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.health = 5
        self.s = scene
        self.pos = position
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setHealth(amount: Int) {
        self.health = amount
    }

    func getHealth() -> Int {
        return self.health
    }

    func drawEnemy() -> SKShapeNode {
        enemy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
        enemy.fillColor = color
        enemy.glowWidth = 0.5
        enemy.strokeColor = color
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.player.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.enemy.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.player.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        enemy.position = pos
        return enemy
    }

}
```

The error comes when I check if `health` grater than `0` or not in `didBegin` function

Comment: You are not subclassing correctly, your enemy is of type SKShapeNode, not of type Enemy

Comment: `enemy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) `<----- see

Comment: yes but if i make it enemy how i make the radius ?]

Comment: I am writing an answer for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not properly subclassing,  You are using your Enemy object as both a factory and an instance,  separate the 2.

Factory:

```
public class EnemyFactory
{
    public func createEnemy(color: SKColor, radius: CGFloat, position: CGPoint) -> Enemy{
        let enemy = Enemy(circleOfRadius: radius)
        enemy.setup(color:color, radius: radius, position: position)
        return enemy
    }
}
```

Instance Class:

```
public class Enemy: SKShapeNode {
    static let Factory = EnemyFactory()
    public var health: Int = 5

    func setup (color: SKColor, radius: CGFloat, position: CGPoint) {
        self.position = position
        fillColor = color
        glowWidth = 0.5
        self.health = 5
        strokeColor = color
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody.isDynamic = true
        physicsBody.collisionBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.player.rawValue
        physicsBody.categoryBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.enemy.rawValue
        physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = GameScene.bodyType.player.rawValue
        physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody = physicsBody
    }
    override init(){
        super.init()

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Some liberties I took:  I removed local redundant variables like color and scene,  you can grab these straight from the object, no need to have another variable to save them.  You also do not need getters and setters,  Swift does this for you already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134109/discussion-between-ahmed-nader-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134126/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-muescha).

Comment: why not use skshapnodes ? they are slower ? @Whirlwind

Comment: yes they are slower, and buggy,  you really should use SKSpriteNode.  Learn how to use SpriteKit first, worry about better performance later

Comment: i know how to use them yes